# Hypervisor detected. Unable to uninstall Hyper-V on Windows 11 (Windows Surface Pro+)

Tags: windows, virtualization, windows-11, hypervisor

I have purchased a new Microsoft Windows Surface Pro 5+. Windows was pre-installed.

I noticed that a 3rd party tool output a warning that my license it not valid for terminals. The developers told me that it was because Hypervisor is detected. And that I needed to un-install Hypervisor.

Their license log says the following:

```
Embedded : no 
Terminal : no 
Citrix : no 
VMWare : no 
VirtualPC : no 
VirtualBox : no 
Hypervisor : yes
```

They use the CPUID function to detect Hypervisor: https://evasions.checkpoint.com/techniques/cpu.html

I opened msinfo32.exe, and it really said "Hypervisor detected:"

[msinfo32.exe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FKBuB.png)

I have tried everything I could do to un-install / disable Hyper-V, but none of the methods proposed on Microsoft Answers worked.

As one can see, I have deactived all virtualization services in Windows Features, but it does not change anything. It still reports that Hyper-V is detected:

[Windows Features](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3nlCz.png)

Using Powershell:

```
Disable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName Microsoft-Hyper-V-Hypervisor"
```

did not work. The error is:

```
Disable-WindowsOptionalFeature : The feature name Microsoft-Hyper-V-Hypervisor is unknown.
+ Disable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName Microsoft-Hyper-V ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Disable-WindowsOptionalFeature], COMException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Dism.Commands.DisableWindowsOptionalFeatureCommand
```

The following also does not work:

```
Disable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName Microsoft-Hyper-V-Hypervisor/Get-Features
```

This also does not work:

```
DISM /Online /Disable-Feature:Microsoft-Hyper-V
```

The error is: (...) is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet (...)

The following cmd statement reports "Successfully executed",
but does not disable Hyper-V:

```
bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype off
```

Comment: Rather than destroy Windows, it's better to analyze the error. What is the tool that issues it? Can you include a screenshot of the message?

Comment: I have added the log to my post.

Comment: But what is this mysterious tool?

Comment: @harrymc It's a browser:  https://www.webkitx.com/

Comment: Because of a browser you wish to destroy Windows? Anyway, a browser should have nothing to do with Hyper-V. I really doubt that this is the reason that it's not working.

Comment: It's a browser activex that I use in my app. I need it. And they have a special pricing / license for VM / terminals. And because Hyper-V is enabled, they see Windows as  running in a VM.

Answer (score 5):

@harrymc: Sometimes there are reasons to get rid of the Hyper-V Modules. This has nothing to do with destroying Windows. You even can't run other Hypervisor like Virtualbox on those systems

Anyway - I got exact the same issue on my Laptop (preinstalled Win11 Home)
For me this was the solution: Go to `Settings` > `Privacy & Security` > `Device Security` > `Core Isolation` > `Memory Integrity` = `OFF`

Reboot and it should work now

[image: Memory Integrity = OFF]

Answer (score 1):

I can't help but laugh at how long this took to figure out. This is what worked for me, in the order I tried. The last step I figured out on my own:

1. Uninstall other hypervisors like VirtualBox
2. Remove the following Windows features:

   - Hyper-V
   - Virtual Machine Platform
   - Windows Hypervisor Platform
   - (maybe) Windows Sandbox
   - (maybe) Windows Subsystem For Linux
3. Disable Windows Security> Device Security> Core Isolation:
   Memory Integrity
4. (Possibly unrelated to your scenario) Uninstalled Bluestacks 5 with [this tool](https://support.bluestacks.com/hc/en-us/articles/360057724751)
5. (What finally worked) Disable Microsoft Defender Device & Credential Guard and all other virtualization-based security features:
   There are a number of sketchy tutorials but I used [this script](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/identity-protection/credential-guard/dg-readiness-tool)

   ...with these parameters:
   DG_Readiness_Tool_v3.6.ps1 -Disable -AutoReboot

*Note, you are disabling security features and all that implies.*